# In bash, Find, Sort and Copy

Tags: bash, sorting, terminal, copy, find

I'm trying to run a search on folder with many folders and files. I would like to find latest 20 quicktimes and copy to specific directory "New_Directory".

So far I got this:

```
find .  -type f -name '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dtl | head -20 | xargs -I{} echo {}
```

This finds me files and prints them with size/date/name (starting with ./)

But if I change command to this (adding cp at the end):

```
find .  -type f -name '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dtl | head -20 | xargs -I{} cp {} /Volume/New_Directory/
```

I get error:

```
cp: illegal option -- w
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- w
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
.... (20 times)
```

I'm using terminal on mac OS.

Please suggest how this can be fixed or please suggest a better approach.
Thank you.

Comment: Try changing cp {} to cp "{}"

Comment: @RamanSailopal did not help, same error... :(

Comment: If you pass the filename to `ls -dtl` you're gonna get more info like the size/date etc as you described. Passing those strings into `cp` is not gonna work. Why the `xargs -0 ls -dtl ` part?

Comment: @0stone0 thank you for comment, I need to sort in date order, searching for newest 20, maybe I can just keep ls -dt, seems working..

Comment: bash `find` has all those requirements build in.

Comment: @0stone0 As far as I know `find` cannot sort its output, especially not by date. Also, there is no "bash `find`", its just a program and completely independent from bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deconstructing your pipeline to see what is happening.

```
find .  -type f -name '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dtl | head -20 |
```

gives you a list of 20 newest `mov` files. The lost looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ljm users 12449464 Jan 10 16:24 ./05ED-E769/DCIM/215___01/IMG_5902.mov
-rw-r--r-- 1 ljm users 14153909 Jan 10 16:00 ./05ED-E769/DCIM/215___01/IMG_5901.mov
-rw-r--r-- 1 ljm users 13819624 Jan 10 15:58 ./05ED-E769/DCIM/215___01/IMG_5900.mov
```

So, your `xargs|cp` will get this as input.

It will be

```
cp -rw-r--r-- 1 ljm users 13819624 Jan 10 15:58 ./05ED-E769/DCIM/215___01/IMG_5900.mov /Volume/New_Directory/
```

If we look at your error message,

```
cp: illegal option -- w
```

`cp -r` is ok, `cp -rw` will produce this message. So that is consistent with what I said.

So, the question is why the `-l` in the copy. If you remove the long format, you get exactly what you need.

As a side note why `ls -d`, if your `find` ensures `-type f`?

```
find .  -type f -name '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -20 | xargs -I{} cp {} /Volume/New_Directory/
```

should do what you want, but remember that you are parsing the output of `ls`, which is considered not a good idea.

Personally, I would

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" |
    sort -n |
    cut -d' ' -f 2- |
    tail -n 20 |
    xargs -I{} cp {} /Volume/New_Directory/
```

Comment: i did remove "-l" as suggested, works like a charm.

Comment: "..parsing the output of ls, which is considered not a good idea." - why not? what would be a better solution? thank you !!!

Comment: When I search in my google bubble for 'parse ls output', the fist hit I get is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead . As a TL;DR: not portable across unices, unexpected handling of special characters and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

you use below script.

```
find . -type f -name '*.mov' | ls -1t | head -n 20 |
xargs -n 1 -I {} realpath {} |
xargs -n 1 -I {} cp {} /Volume/New_Directory/
```